# autotest failed with wrong title

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the ruby on rails tutorial. I am running autotest and have a error that I cannot fix. I have recheck my work perhaps 15 times and still everything is the same as the video word for word.

Here's the error.

```
4 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:12 # PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
```

Here's the pages_controller_spec file https://gist.github.com/4565204 and home_html file https://gist.github.com/4565209

Anyone know how I can fix this error? As 'home' has the right title in these files.

Answer (score 0):

In the row 14 you should use :text instead of :content

```
response.should have_selector('title', text: '...')
```

Comment: Added, and it gives "/Users/lexi87/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end" I added a additional "end" same error.

Comment: an error is here
     'text: => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Samp...'
you should use either
     'text: "Ruby...'
or
     ':text => "Ruby...'

Syntax 'text:' is an alias for the ':text =>'